# How can i see the content of a list in python after taking input from the user and appending it to the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
n = int(input())
mat = []
for i in range(n):
    row = map(int, input().split())
    mat.append(row)

print(mat)
```

when i run this code i get the following o/p

**[map object at 0x7f30e08ccba8, map object at 0x7f30df3a3438, map object at 0x7f30df3a3518]**

Comment: Try `row = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Answer (score 4):

The map object in 3.6 returns an iterator. You need to iterate all its values either by printing each single item, or simply wrapping it into a `list( map(...., ...))` statement:

```
n = int(input())
mat = []
for i in range(n):
    row = list ( map(int, input().split()) ) # iterate all the values immediately
    mat.append(row)

print(mat)
```

For python 2.x the `map` command produces a list directly.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map